# xamarin.forms read app version from app store / google store

Tags: app-store, xamarin.forms

I need to know when i start running my app if a new version exists in Google Play Store / ios app store.

I want to do it by comparing my running app version to the one in the store.

How do i read the app version from the store in run time ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string url = "http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=YourBundelID";

using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    string jsonString = webClient.DownloadString(string.Format(url));

    var lookup = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonString);


    if (lookup != null
        && lookup.Count >= 1
        && lookup["resultCount"] != null
        && Convert.ToInt32(lookup["resultCount"].ToString()) > 0)
     {

        var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<object>>(lookup[@"results"].ToString());


        if (results != null && results.Count > 0)
        {
            var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(results[0].ToString());
            appStoreAppVersion = values.ContainsKey("version") ? values["version"].ToString() : string.Empty;
        }
    }
}

return appStoreAppVersion;
```

Answer (score 2):

If there's no easy way to achieve this, build your own easy way ;-) 
For example: with every upload to the app store you upload the current version info to an online resource you can access from your app. All you need is a webserver where you can either run your own API or just upload a file containing the version info.

Maybe not a solution you awaited, but it's definitely going to work.

Answer (score 1):

There is no (easy) way to do that. The best way to do it would be to access the app details through some API but I don't think they make that (publicly) available. So the other way would probably to scrape the according sites, but I'm pretty sure they will be unhappy with that method and maybe their license even forbids it.

Also, mostly that kind of solutions is due to poor design. The user has to be able to use the old version for the length of days, although you should strive for fast adoption of your new version.
But just keep in mind while designing your backend etc. that you have to be backwards compatible.

Lastly, as a user I really hate those kind of messages. Depending on what kind of app it is I just want to use it then, not be forced to update, so go out, update, and try to do the thing I opened it for in the first place.